# File upload not working

Tags: php, file-upload

I installed wordpress in a media temple server and noticed that couldn't upload files. After tryng several solutions decided to replicate the problem with a simple script (http://pastie.org/2349720).

```
<?php
if($_FILES)
        print_r($_FILES);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else if (!file_exists($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]))
      {
      echo 'temp file doesn\'t exists';
      }
    else
      {
      $uploaded=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      if($uploaded)
        echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      else
        echo "fallo la carga del archivo";
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>

<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Looks like move_upload_file() is returning false without a warning or error, looked in php documentation and found this

> If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and
>   move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.

I've checked and the file upload doesn't report any errors and the temporary file exist before trying to move it. Already set 777 permission in folder and still not having any luck, any idea on what can be causing this behavior and how to fix it?

thanks.

Comment: set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before your code and look at error/warning given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i had fastCGI disabled, i've just enabled and things are working as expected. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What does this give you:

```
$_FILES[...]['error']
```

If it doesn't give you zero, you can check what goes wrong here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php.

If it does, make sure the folder your folder in is accessible by PHP. You could try running this command:

```
sudo -s -u [php_user]
cd [destination_directory]
```

Check whether you can reach the directory =)!

Comment: $_FILES[...]['error'] in all my upload test were 0.

i logged with the apache user and were able to copy files to the folder.

Answer (score 1):

`move_uploaded_file` will also fail if the destination is not writable.  Is the root folder writable (I ask that because you aren't tacking on the uploads folder into the filename when moving it).  I know you mentioned you set the permission to `777` but is that for the uploads directory or the entire folder that the application is in.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking whether destination exists in certain directory and then copying source to *another* directory:

```
if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
...
$uploaded=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try absolute paths for the destination of `move_uploaded_file()`

Answer (score 0):

check if u can reach d dir, There is no need in deleting it in temporary folder since it will be moved automatically,the target destination is still within d file. so why dont you try moving it to another destination

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but I found this problem a few hours ago and the problem was the write permissions of my folder (I don't own the server I was working on) and the response for the people I work with was

> The "yours" folder must be writable by the user apache runs as (www-data) this can be accomplished by making the folder world writable or setting the "where you want to put your files" folder to be owned by group www-data and make it group writable.